# Escape double quote Character in Kognitio

Tags: kognitio-wx2, kognitio, wx2

It seems that the Kognito console use this template for password reset (also create user)

`ALTER USER user_name ALTER PASSWORD TO "         "; -- we cannot include a " character in the password which would end up in syntax error.`

How do we escape this and include a `"` character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found one solution from the manual

```
ALTER USER user_name ALTER PASSWORD TO 'Pass"word' ESCAPE '"';
```